# CSS / HTML - Div or not? (Best Practice)

Tags: html, css

I have been building a website and trying to apply most of the HTML5 / CSS3 and I got myself to a question.

So, I had the following CSS...

```
section.t aside div.bio{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

section.t aside div.bio p{
    color: #555;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

And the HTML...

```
<aside>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">###</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bio">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Then I changed the CSS to...

```
section.t aside p.bio{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

So the last part of the HTML simplified as...

```
<aside>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">###</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="bio">Bio</p>
</aside>
```

Basically, I did drop the div wrapping the p, and give the p the style. The result is exactly the same.

My question is if there are any advantage of wrapping things inside a div like in the first case? or not?

I did get to realize my whole website pretty much is without div tags anymore. Is thre any consequence for that? is that either a bad practice or cause any seo troubles?

Comment: I dont think so, div has specific semantic meaning and shouldn't be used just for its default styling.  Afaik your aside tag handles that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no bad practice to not using divs when other tags are more appropriate. You may find it hard to combine parts of your code into groups without container divs, but other than those specific use-cases, there's no real downside.

When there is no other new tag that defines the content you're using, then `<div>` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, in some cases I need it to wrap some code. So... in this specific case I do not benefit nothing from having a div wrapping the p, since the p can have the same result itself?

Comment: @user2840318 Correct. If you wanted to add another `<p>` after `<p class="bio"> and style them together, it would be better practice to add a container div, since that better explains semantically how you want your content to be grouped, and in many cases would require less CSS to achieve.

Comment: I actually have in a different place two <p> and in that case I did use the p + p css to style the second. But I understand your point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no need for a `div` then absolutely remove it.  There is no point cluttering up your markup just for the sake of it.

My workflow when it comes to writing HTML is to write it as a document first.  So only adding the semantic markup that is necessary for the document to read correctly.

Then when it comes to styling the document if I need to use elements like `div` or `span` for presentational purposes then I will, because that is what they are for.

Comment: "write it as a document first" -> this is a good workflow and I wish more people practiced it!